# How to get absolute path with proper character encoding in Java?

Tags: java, eclipse, encoding, utf-8

I'd like to get the absolute path of a file, so that I can use it further to locate this file. I do it the following way:

```
File file = new File(Swagger2MarkupConverterTest.class.getResource(
            "/json/swagger.json").getFile());   
String tempPath = file.getAbsolutePath();
String path = tempPath.replace("\\", "\\\\");
```

The path irl looks like this:

```
C:\\Users\\Michał Szydłowski\\workspace2\\swagger2markup\\bin\\json\\swagger.json
```

However, since it contains Polish characters and spaces, what I get from `getAbsolutPath` is:

```
C:\\Users\\Micha%c5%82%20Szyd%c5%82owski\\workspace2\\swagger2markup\\bin\\json\\swagger.json
```

How can I get it to do it the right way? This is problematic, because with this path, it cannot locate the file (says it doesn't exist).

Comment: Tried with getCanonicalPath?

Comment: Maybe this is a kind of confusion with the output device.  Are you trying to ouput your special characters through windows console?  Have you tried to output it to a file with a Writer with the proper encoding?  Maybe your data have been always well and the problem lies in Windows console painting it wrong

Comment: But it isn't a matter of displaying in console. The path is clearly wrong, because when I use it as an argument to a function opening the file, it says it doesn't exist. If I copy and paste raw path, with Polish characters properly encoded, it works fine.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `URL.getFile` call you are using returns the file part of a URL encoded according to the URL encoding rules. You need to decode the string using `URLDecoder` before giving it to `File`:

```
String path = Swagger2MarkupConverterTest.class.getResource(
        "/json/swagger.json").getFile();

path = URLDecoder.decode(path, "UTF-8");

File file = new File(path);
```

From Java 7 onwards you can use `StandardCharsets.UTF_8`

```
path = URLDecoder.decode(path, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way, that doesn't involve decoding anything, is this:

```
URL resource = YourClass.class.getResource("abc");
Paths.get(resource.toURI()).toFile();
// or, equivalently:
new File(resource.toURI());
```

It doesn't matter now where the file in the classpath physically is, it will be found as long as the resource is actually a file and not a JAR entry.

Answer (score 0):

```
URI uri = new File(Swagger2MarkupConverterTest.class.getResource(
            "/json/swagger.json").getFile()).toURI(); 
File f = new File(uri);
System.out.println(f.exists());
```

You can use `URI` to encode your path, and open `File` by `URI`.

Comment: okay, so how do I extract a path from it? I have a function, that needs a file path. with complete, unabridged characters

Comment: @MichałSzydłowski `f.getpath()`

Answer (score 0):

You can use simply

```
File file = new File("file_path");
String charset = "UTF-8";
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    new FileInputStream(file), charset));
```

give the charset at the time of read the file.